# Why does the Community user mark questions as duplicates?

Tags: support, closed-questions, exact-duplicates, community-user

I recently came across [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1131374/513819) which has been marked as a duplicate. What's strange is that this question has been marked as a duplicate by the [Community user](https://superuser.com/users/-1/community):

[image: marked as duplicate by Community]

How can Community mark a question as a duplicate if he's not a real person? Was it a moderator who marked the question as a duplicate? Was it an anonymous user? Or did something else happen?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When a "duplicate" close vote or flag is cast, a box appears above the question visible to the question's owner. It prompts the author to either edit the question to clarify its non-duplicateness or accept the duplicity by pressing a "yes, that solved my problem" button.

If the user chooses that button, the Community user casts the final duplicate vote, thereby saving close vote reviewers the trouble of closing a question that the author knows is a duplicate.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250922/can-we-clarify-to-the-op-that-their-question-is-not-yet-closed-and-the-duplicate/250930#250930

Comment: I wanted to mark this question as a duplicate but couldn't find one on meta.su :)